# How does other app like (whatsapp, facebook) work without implement scoped storage

Tags: java, android, scoped-storage

My app is getting

```
/storage/emulated/0/PDFfiles/20210809_171942_pdf.pdf: open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

in android version-11 . In lower versions it's working. I want to know how WhatsApp deals with files without getting scoped storage permission.

Comment: In some cases, they still have `targetSdkVersion 29`. That will not be an option in a couple of months. In other cases, they are pre-installed apps, which can have rights that ordinary apps cannot.

Comment: But the privacy policy must be same for all

Comment: WhatsApp is not a pre-installed app on my device. I need to download it from Play Store. Do you think Google has a package whitelisting, so only certain apps can create their own folder under external storage without any permission? @CommonsWare

Comment: @AnggrayudiH: I doubt that Google does, but the device manufacturer might.

Comment: @CommonsWare I guess so. I wonder if we can create a dummy app using WhatsApp package, and then test if we can use `java.io.File` to write files under `storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp`